# Compiling glibc 2.4, issue during configure

Tags: compilation, glibc, autoconf

I'm compiling glibc 2.4 following this procedure [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5). However, I can't pass the configure step. 
When I reach the `checking whether autoconf works` step, it stays there for more than 24 hours.

Comment: You are following instructions for upgrading to GLIBC-2.14, but your question is about GLIBC-2.4. Which version are you *actually* trying to install?